# pytest: why use a src layout?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm following this *non-src* layout as shown in [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules) doc:

```
setup.py
mypkg/
    ...
tests/
    __init__.py
    foo/
        __init__.py
        test_view.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        test_view.py
```

The doc says:

> Now pytest will load the modules as `tests.foo.test_view` and `tests.bar.test_view`, allowing you to have modules with the same name. But now this introduces a subtle problem: in order to load the test modules from the `tests` directory, pytest prepends the root of the repository to `sys.path`, which adds the side-effect that now `mypkg` is also importable. This is problematic if you are using a tool like tox to test your package in a virtual environment, because you want to test the installed version of your package, not the local code from the repository.
>
> In this situation, it is **strongly** suggested to use a `src` layout where application root package resides in a sub-directory of your root...

But [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#basic-example) says it will sdist-package, install and test.

So this is what I don't understand:

> ...because you want to test the installed version of your package, not the local code from the repository...

I think most of the time during development what we want to test **is** the local code from the repository. This is usually the development or nightly branch, not the stable branch that may be installed on our system.

And I did some experiments. I create a software package `mypkg`, installed its stable branch, and then modified some code in development branch to break the test. If `mypkg` is not put under `src` dir, then pytest will test *local code* because it can find `mypkg` package on the local path, and the test will break as expected. However, if `mypkg` is put under `src` dir, then pytest will instead test *installed code* because it can only find `mypkg` there, and the test won't break while it should.

So only the *non-src* layout is working as expected. It works as expected even with tox: tox will sdist and install the package in an isolated environment, which is not affected by `mypkg` in local path. So tox is indeed testing local code, not installed code. This is what we expect.

Given that *non-src* layout works correctly, why would the doc say it is *a subtle problem* and *strongly* recommend using a *src* layout?

Edit. Didn't expect this to be a [debate](https://github.com/pypa/python-packaging-user-guide/issues/320).

Comment: You are right that you want to test the latest code.  But you want to test it as it is installed, not as it sits in your working tree.  The src layout makes accidental importing from the working tree impossible.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I see there is such a difference, but 2 questions: 1. Suppose working tree is clean, what would pass the test of working tree but fail when installed? 2. If using tox, tox will do sdist and install, so there is no need to use the src layout to prevent accidental imports from working tree?

Comment: Make sure to install with `--editable` flag. Why to use a src directory is well explained by hynek [here](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/).

Comment: @wim Thank you, will read. But a short question for now: Following `install -e`, what if your system also needs a stable version of the same software running while you are developing on the bleeding edge? Is it best practice to remove the stable version from user install and reinstall it in another isolated environment?

Comment: The development version (i.e. the one installed editable) should be installed within a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: @wim The article you posted above actually links to a very long [discussion](https://github.com/pypa/python-packaging-user-guide/issues/320). I'm reading that. But to make it short, if the dev version is to be installed with an env then you should go into that env and run tests there. It's the package not working tree that's installed, whether src-layout or not, right? So I still don't see why `src` is helpful.

Comment: @Cyker One use-case where this matters is If your package has any C-extensions that need to be compiled, and installed, in the right place.

Comment: @Cyker Ned already explained it in the first comment here. And Hynek explained it in article. You need to test that the packaging/installer has worked too, otherwise you can publish a completely broken package that has passed tests only because of your cwd and the fact that `sys.path` starts with empty string. Maybe you have to get bitten by this issue on your own project to truly understand it   :)

Comment: @wim I almost got bitten but did I tell you I put tests under `tests/tests`?

Comment: There are lots of things that can be wrong in setup.py that would make your installed code different than your working tree. C extensions were mentioned above. You could omit packages or data files, or forget to register entry points.  Setup.py is code: how do you test it?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Thank you for pointing out `setup.py`. I agree that testing the packaged and installed software is the sound approach. But testing working tree is still good, quick and effective in discovering problems. You can use quick tests to *discover* problems and slow tests to *verify* problems are fixed. Well, there's the halting problem so you can't verify everything but it's off-topic here.